# When and why to use initWithNibName:bundle: in development

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, xib

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
```

Why we use this method? Is it necessary when using xib file?

Comment: possibly duplicate [when should i initialize a view controller using initwithnibname](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224077/when-should-i-initialize-a-view-controller-using-initwithnibname)

Answer (score 0):

Why we use init with nib ?

So we can take a view created with interface builder and initialize a view from that instead of coding everything yourself.

it is a good alternative to coding everything if you just need basic things.