# PushViewController to navigate to next stack

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

I am new to IOS .what I am doing is I just simply placed a `UIButton` on my main view and I want when I click on that button i t should take me to the next stack . for that what I am doing is

```
-(IBAction)stack:(id)sender{
 Page1 *button =[[Page1 alloc]init];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:button animated:YES];
}
```

I simply add this in my code ...but it is not working.

Do I need to put `UINavigationController` in main view or in `AppDelegate` to press button and create new stack with navigation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in AppDelegate,

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
```

and change your button press method,

```
-(IBAction)stack:(id)sender{
    Page1 *button =[[Page1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page1" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:button animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: ya thanks for help and it works ..can you tell me why we added UINavigationController in appDelegate??

Comment: and if we need to press button and create a new stack without UINavigationController then what can we do??

Comment: Page1 *button =[[Page1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page1" bundle:nil]; [self presentViewController:button animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: If you don't want to use a navigation controller here, Without changing App Delegate, try this code for button press: -(IBAction)stack:(id)sender{
    Page1 *button =[[Page1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page1" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:button animated:YES completion:nil];
}

Comment: ya thanks man !! it works but like others saying to add nib name ,..whats the difference if i make use of nib name in code??

Comment: When we create an object of an existing viewcontroller (in your case Page1), when we initialise the controller, we have to provide the name of the .xib file you have used. I have done that part in my code. :)

Comment: ok If we dont give that nib name and directly initializes like i did in my code...does it make difference?>

Comment: ya simply i used Page1 *button =[[Page1 alloc]init];
and it also works

Comment: this will help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224077/when-should-i-initialize-a-view-controller-using-initwithnibname

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(void)aboutButtonPressed {
    AboutViewController *aboutView =[[AboutViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"About" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:aboutView animated:YES];
    [aboutView release];
}
```

Comment: just by adding nibname ...how can i navigate ..if I have not UINavigationController in the appdelegate??

Comment: if you are using storyboard just embed the navigation controller or create its instance in appdelegate

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to write following lines in appdel

```
self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following thing:
**In AppDelegate.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

**In AppDelegate.m**

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize navigationController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

and when you want to push the next viewcontroller , you can write the above code :

```
-(void)fontButtonPress{
      FontViewController *fontViewController = [[FontViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"FontViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:fontViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Let Me know if You have any issue.

Thanks